# Is using Hibernate's @Entity Object as key in a map safe?

Tags: hibernate

Is it safe to use an object annotated with Hibernate's `@Entity` as the key in a map? Safe meaning I expect two keys are the same if the object's database ids are the same. I'm using it in a transaction scope with no detached objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you acknowledge that two objects are equal when the ids are the same (which you just did), you should override `hashCode` and `equals` based on that. If you've done so, these objects are safe to use as keys. Of course assuming these ids don't change.

Edit: restricting these ids from changing restricts you from creating and adding an object as key to a collection *before* it is persisted. It is generally recommended to [use a business key in your `hashCode` and `equals`](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode).

Comment: Do the annotated `@Entity` objects have a default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` method using the id property?

Comment: No, Hibernate does not add or override these methods for us. The default implementations are the ones from `Object`.